# How to append a column to a dynamically generated table in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I have an app where I am fetching data from the database and displaying it on the frontend in a tabular format.

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name </th>
      <th>Value1 </th>
      <th>Value2 </th>
      <th>Result </th>
      <th>Set/Unset </th>
    <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let arr of exArr; let i = index">
        <td>{{ arr.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ arr.Value1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ arr.Value2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ arr.Result }}</td>
        <td>
           <form [formGroup]="myForm" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="btn-group" btnRadioGroup formControlName="radio">
                    <label btnRadio="Include" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="0" role="button" (click)="onClickSet()">Set</label>
                    <label btnRadio="Exclude" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="0" role="button" (click)="onClickUnset()">Unset</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      radio: null
    });

    this.dataService.getReport()
    .subscribe(exArr =>
      this.exArr = exArr
    )

  }
```

As shown in the code, only four values are fetched from the database, while the `button` / `Set/Unset` is added to each of the row that is generated from angular itself.

The app is getting all the data from the backend through `exArr` while the button column is in no way a part of it.

I want to find a way to append this static column of `Set/Unset` values to table data that is fetched so that I can send it back to the backend and perform different operations based on the selection value of the buttton

Comment: you just want to send an id or what ever value you need into the Set/Unset methods? onClickSet(arr.id)

Comment: Hi @David, it works fine till that but i want to return the entire column of set/unset values and append that column to the object data received from the backend so that it forms a set of object data together.

Comment: just pass arr then.

Answer (score 0):

What about passing the index `i` to both methods `onClickSet` and `onClickUnset` when the data does not have an unique identifier.

**Markup**

```
<label btnRadio="Include"
       class="btn btn-primary"
       tabindex="0"
       role="button" 
       (click)="onClickSet(i)">Set</label>
<label btnRadio="Exclude"
       class="btn btn-primary"
       tabindex="0"
       role="button"
       (click)="onClickUnset(i)">Unset</label>
```

**Controller:**

```
public onClickSet(index:number){
    console.log('onClickSet item is ', this.exArr[index]); 
}

public onClickUnset(index:number){
    console.log('onClickUnset item is ', this.exArr[index]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly pass in the entire row.

```
(change)="onClickSet(arr)"
```

With this find the row in your data array using **find** and then update the label like so, this is done by name it would be better if you used an id.

```
onClickSet(arr) {    
    console.log(arr);

    const a = this.exArr.find(x => x.Name == arr.Name);
    console.log(a);

    a.label = "set";

    console.log(this.exArr)
  }
```

Do the same for the unset function, or create a method to reduce repetitive code.

```
updateSetState() { } for example.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 name = 'Angular';
  exArr=[{Name:"a",Value1:"v1"},
  {Name:"b",Value1:"v2"},
  {Name:"c",Value1:"v3"}]

  ngOnInit() {
    for(var i=0;this.exArr.length;i++){
      this.exArr[i]["label"]=null
    }
  }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
  }
onClickSet(i,set){
this.exArr[i]["label"]=set
}
onClickUnset(i,unset){
  this.exArr[i]["label"]=unset

}
test(){
  console.log(this.exArr)
}
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name </th>
      <th>Value1 </th>
      <th>Value2 </th>
      <th>Result </th>
      <th>Set/Unset </th>
    <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let arr of exArr; let i = index">
        <td>{{ arr.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ arr.Value1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ arr.Result }}</td>
        <td>
                  <div class="btn-group" >
<input type="radio" id="ritemb" (change)="onClickSet(i,'set')" >    set
<input type="radio" id="ritemb" (change)="onClickUnset(i,'unset')">                 Unset
                  </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button (click)="test()">test</button>
```

I hope this will help you, no need of forms
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8uzuyr?file=src/app/app.component.ts
just check the console after clicking on the test button

Comment: The data gets updated fine except for the fact the selection is applied to only 1 radio button out of the entire column. I want users to be able to see their selection before pressing the test button.

Comment: Both `set` and `unset` are selectable now and can't be un selected. The data is correctly set based on the last radio selection but the display is still a problem.